# How IIS 80 port webstie set one sub-app only intranet and other internet?

Tags: iis

e.g,my iis folder directory structure like :

```
IIS
 |-default app (80 port)
   |- Aapp
   |- Bapp
   |- Capp
```

I can set all 80 port app have internet premission,but i have trouble when I'd like to set Aapp only `intranet` premission and other app Bapp,Capp have `internet` premission.

expected :

- user on `internet` link `https://mycompany.com/Aapp` get `404` status code
- user on `intranet` link `https://192.168.1.1/Aapp` get `200` status code
- user on `internet` link `https://mycompany.com/Bapp` get `200` status code

Comment: Write URL rewrite rule to return 404 for certain requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intranet IP segement looks like 192.168.x.x. Then you could set the rule like this to exclude intranet IP address. In this case, all IP doesn't match your intranet net will be blocked by Aapp.

```xml
<rule name="rewrite  rule1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="Aapp" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="192\.168\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="404" subStatusCode="0" statusReason="Internet access not allowed" statusDescription="Not found" />
</rule>
```

If 404 response is not necessarily.Then you can set domain and IP restriction rule for each application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh831785(v=ws.11)

Comment: Apparently an IP restriction rule can also return `404 Not Found`, search for `Deny Action Type` in the link you provided. I personally would go with that.